# How to convert string to date format (duplicate)

Tags: c#

I have save only year from datetime picker into the database.

```
     sesiontimepicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    sesiontimepicker.CustomFormat = "yyyy";

     cmd.Parameters.Add("@sesion", sesiontimepicker.Text);
```

Using this code only year has been save in the database .Now I want to retreive it
but it give an error of "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime" .

```
       sesiontimepicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(read["sesion"]);

                sesiontimepicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                sesiontimepicker.CustomFormat = "yyyy";
```

Any body can help how to solve this .

Comment: How can just a year be converted to a DateTime?

Comment: Even if you did this, like `new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yearFromDatabase),x,x)` What will you insert instead of x,x? an arbitrary values for month and day?

Comment: sesiontimepicker.Value = new DateTime(1, 1, Convert.ToInt(read["sesion"]); Note this will fail if read["sesion"] is empty or null. I'd also like to point out that the spelling is "session"

Comment: I thnk you have to read my question again clearly I mentioned  I only saved year i.e 2017 in database from datetimepicker now I want to retrieve it and show in datetimepicker

Comment: You need to feed it a date then as mentioned by others above. 2017 is not a  date and will not be parsed or converted to one. You will need to do Mahmoud or Kevin's suggestion and hope specifying January 1st is okay to use.

Comment: We read your question fine. As the runtime so elegantly pointed out however, a year alone is not a valid date. You will need to add a month and day to it to make a date out of it.

Comment: what is the type of the database column? do you store the year as string?

Comment: yeas I stored year as a string

Comment: Then give this to the date time picker: `sesiontimepicker.Value = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(read["sesion"]), 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to change the column type to a `DateTime` kind of type and store the `sesiontimepicker.Value` instead of the `sesiontimepicker.Text`.

If you can't do this, you have to parse the returned string into an `int` and create a `DateTime` using an arbitrary month and day (since you don't care about them anyway):

```
sesiontimepicker.Value = new DateTime (Convert.ToInt32(read["sesion"]), 1, 1);
```